# getting title of page using simple html dom?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get the title from an external site using simple html dom (the title of page between the TITLE tags) but it's not retrieving anything.  Any ideas?

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load('http://www.google.com');
$titleraw = $html->find('title');
$title = $titleraw->title;
```

Comment: Why not just use preg_match()?

Answer (score 3):

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('http://www.google.com'); 
$titleraw = $html->find('title',0);
$title = $titleraw->innertext;
```

`$html->load_file()` Loads contents from a from a file or a URL.

`$html->find('title')` will return an array

and `$titleraw->innertext` returns content of title element

Answer (score 2):

`->load()` expects a string containing HTML, not a URL.

Try:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://google.com');
```

instead.

Beyond that, note that google's ToS forbid screen scrapers, so hopefully you're just using that url as a fill-in example rather than whatever you're really trying to scrape.

Answer (score 2):

Simply

```
$mypage=file_get_html('http://myurl.com');
$title=$mypage->find('title',0);
echo $title->plaintext;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(
  preg_match(
    '~<title>(.*)</title>~si',
    file_get_contents('http://www.google.com'),
    $result
  );
  var_dump($result[1]);
}else{ /* no result */ }
```

Else

```
$titleraw = $html->xpath('//title');
```

Comment: The OP specifically ask for a Simple HTML DOM solution, why suggest this?

Comment: For this simple task I strongly recommend a regular expression. SimpleHtml and other DOM/HTML/XML parsers are very sensible. If there is ANY syntax error anywhere on the REMOTE page there will be no result at all!

Comment: I was/am already using simple html dom to pull something else successfully, so I figured I'd keep using it.  Is it overkill (aka not efficient) to use a regular expression AND simple html dom?

Comment: and regex isnt sensible? what if there is an attribute in the title?

Comment: @powtac yeah, there you have it. You have to change the regex whereas with DOM/XPath you wouldnt because DOM/XPath knows what a local name is, while Regex doesnt. With DOM/XPath you just fetch the title. It's really regex that's brittle, because it doesnt know what a node is :)

Comment: For other tags than `title` I would not recommend the reg exp, because title is the only tag where attributes make no sense...

Comment: `dir="rtl"` makes perfect sense on the title-tag.

Comment: I've noticed the regex fails when there is a break after <title> ... for example, view source for http://www.myspace.com/Maroon5

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();  
$html->load('http://www.google.com');
$titleraw = $html->find('title');
foreach($html->find('title') as $link_element) {        
    echo $link_element->plaintext;
}
```

instead of `$title = $titleraw->title;`

Answer (score 0):

Using DOM and xpath you can do:

```
function getTitle($url) {
   libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
   $doc = new DOMDocument();
   $doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
   $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
   $nlist = $xpath->query("//head/title");
   return $nlist->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
echo "Title: " . getTitle("http://www.google.com") . "\n";
```

Comment: a foreach loop to return the first item? Painful. Why not just `$nlist->item(0)->nodeValue`?

Comment: Actually in the very first iteration it is returned so loop is not really iterated there. But I edited my answer to `return $nlist->item(0)->nodeValue;` now.

Comment: There's still overhead for setting up the loop.

Comment: I have already removed the look with `return $nlist->item(0)->nodeValue;`. However I really don't know how much overhead that foreahch & return would have cost over this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$oHtml = str_get_html($url);
$Title = array_shift($oHtml->find('title'))->innertext;
$Description = array_shift($oHtml->find("meta[name='description']"))->content;
$keywords = array_shift($oHtml->find("meta[name='keywords']"))->content;
echo $title;
echo $Description;
echo $keywords;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$html = new simple_html_dom()
$data = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('title') as $element)
       echo $element->plaitext . '<br>';
```